# Meteor build is hanging with Docker build but working inside the container

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, meteor, windows-server

I am trying to create a docker file to create a windows container with meteor app bundle. But my docker build hangs at "meteor build" step and sometime it completes in hours.

```
ONBUILD RUN meteor build --server-only --allow-superuser --directory "c:\tmp\bundle-dir" --architecture os.windows.x86_64
```

But if i commented this step and completes my docker build to create a windows server 2019 based docker image than build completes successfully. And I can run "meteor build" inside the container, after running a container with this image.

```
docker run -it <image_name> cmd
```

I dont know what is going on here. My changes are available on github at https://github.com/singh-ajeet/meterd-windows.

I am using Google cloud VM with configuration - 8 core and 30GB RAM.